# Mismatch with expected vs. actual results Dredd

Tags: swagger, dredd

Currently I'm running the uber.yaml found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/uber.yaml). I'm currently getting mismatches on the actual versus expected values:

```
expected:
headers:
Content-Type: application/json

actual:
statusCode: 301
headers:
server: nginx
date: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 20:32:28 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 178
location: https://api.uber.com/v1/history
connection: close
age: 0
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I have edited the the uber.yaml to include an expected content-type as follows:

```
- name: Content-Type
    in: header
    type: string
    required: true
    default: application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the API responds with status code 301 and Content Type text/html, but your API description says it should respond with Content Type application/json.